# Возможно ли запустить базу ElephantSql с бэкап и обратно загрузить бэкап?

Tags: postgresql, резервное-копирование

Хочу использовать на время разработки сервис ElephantSql, но непонятно как создать базу на сайте через мой бэкап базы данных.

Локально у меня стоит PostgreSQL, данные, связи все сделано, хотелось бы его загрузить на elephantsql, сделать клиент на replit, а после завершения разработки скачать копию базы и уже развернуть на своём сервера.

Подскажите, даёт ли такую возможность Elephant SQL ?

Comment: В интерфейсе на вкладке BACKUP имеется кнопка "Upload backup".

Comment: Нет такой кнопки. Может быть нужно выбрать платный план

Comment: Документация может недоговаривать - но не врёт. Может, и правда, нужен небесплатный тарифный план. Но в любом случае на бесплатном тарифе вроде доступны и терминальный psql, и pgadmin - попробуй загрузить дамп через них.